# How to assign columns (and column ranges) to separate array variables?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, micro-optimization

Suppose I have the following (newline-separated) array in Bash (4.3):

```
abc  def  ghi  jkl        # ${myArray[0]}
abc  def  ghi  jkl  mno   # ${myArray[1]}
abc  def  ghi             # ${myArray[2]}
...
```

I would like to split this up columnwise, into the following array variables:

```
# First column
abc  # ${myArray_col1[0]}
abc  # ${myArray_col1[1]}
abc  # ${myArray_col1[2]}
...

# Second column
def  # ${myArray_col2[0]}
def  # ${myArray_col2[1]}
def  # ${myArray_col2[2]}
...


# Third column, and all following
ghi  jkl        # ${myArray_col3_and_onward[0]}
ghi  jkl  mno   # ${myArray_col3_and_onward[1]}
ghi             # ${myArray_col3_and_onward[2]}
...
```

I know many ways in which this can be done (`awk`, `read -a`, etc.), and most involve a loop of some sort.

However, the simplest, shortest and fastest way I've been able to come up with, is this:

```
myArray_col1=($(echo ${myArray[*]} | cut -f 1 -d ' '))
myArray_col2=($(echo ${myArray[*]} | cut -f 2 -d ' '))
myArray_col3_and_onward=($(echo ${myArray[*]} | cut -f 4- -d ' '))
```

(with `$IFS` set to newline of course).

Although this suits my needs perfectly fine, there is this part of me that's just plain annoyed by the seemingly unnecessary triple call to `echo` and `cut` :)

Is there any way that this can be avoided? I'm looking for something like:

```
(MAGIC SYNTAX HERE)=($(echo ${myArray[*]} | cut -f 1,2,4- -d ' '))
```

NOTE: the way in which I've obtained the original array is already the most convenient/fastest in many senses (and moreover, it's out of my direct control :)), so I'd rather not touch that.

Answer (score 2):

`bash` doesn't really have this type of transposition built-in, but the following loop should be sufficient (with no external processes needed).

```
for row in "${myArray[@]}"; do
    read col1 col2 col3plus <<< "$row"
    myArray_col1+=( "$col1" )
    myArray_col2+=( "$col2" )
    myArray_col3_and_onward+=( "$col3plus" )
done
```

Comment: +1, although it's not quite the elegance I was hoping for...It can actually be quite a bit slower than repeated `cuts` for large input arrays; I suspect that's because this loop requires dynamic array resizing, whereas the `cut` knows beforehand how large the output array will be. Plus, note that my `$IFS` is set to newline, to the `read` doesn't split correctly unless setting it to space.

Comment: You can locally override `IFS` in `IFS=$'\n' read col1 col2 col3plus <<< "$row"`. `bash` really isn't suited for this type of use; it's a glue language for tying together other programs. Once you reach a certain level of data processing, you're better off switching to a more general-purpose programming language.

Comment: One is not always free to choose the language. More importantly, believe it or not, I'm not processing data, I'm gluing :)